# Specific database table register permission

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I will explain this with an example from the beginning:

I've got this table 'database.dbo.table1' which has this data:

```
**userID | amount | Units** 
1      | 300    | 2
2      | 150    | 2
3      | 120    | 1
1      | 80     | 16
3      | 130    | 8
```

I've create 1 user in database for each userID existed:

```
user_1
user_2
user_3
```

I want that, if user 1 want to make a `select * from database.dbo.table1` the user needs to see just this:

```
**userID | amount | Units** 
1      | 300    | 2
1      | 80     | 16
```

Without seeing the data from other users.

Can I do this with permissions granted from database putting a condition like "if is user_1 who's doing the select, give him just the data when userID = '1'?

or maybe

I can do this with a trigger every time the users wants to do a select and change in the background the user select?

Is the first time I have to separate info from a table depending on a register based on a user logged in.

Comment: What RDBMS is this?

Comment: The RDBMS is Microsoft SQLServer MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to realize that is probably creating views like

```
CREATE VIEW `database.dbo.table1_user1` AS SELECT * 
FROM `database.dbo.table1`
WHERE **userID = 1;
```

for every user. You have also change permissions, so that the users can only access this view.

If the users do not access the database directly you could solve this issue programmatically.

**UPDATE**

There is also the possiblity to create one view for all users and use the `CURRENT_USER()` function (mysql)
Then the CREATE Statement would look like

```
CREATE VIEW `database.dbo.table1_view` AS SELECT * 
FROM `database.dbo.table1`
WHERE **userID = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_USER(), 6, 1);
```

Thank you jarlh for noting this possibility

Comment: Why not one common view for all users, with a CURRENT_USER condition?

Comment: I agree, that would be a valid solution aswell, I'll add this to the answer!

Comment: @jarlh how can I put Current_User ass a condition into the sentence?

Comment: join a separate table storing all users and their userids.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to using a view, which is a fine approach, SQL Server supports [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15), which will filter rows based on the user without having to introduce views.